# Python internal pipe in subprocess using list arguments?

Tags: python, subprocess

It is possible to create a subprocess like this...

`commandlist = ['cat', '/some/file']`

`sp = subprocess.Popen(commandlist)`

But is it possible to pipe the output of that sequence into another command inside the same subprocess?

For example, what would be the sequence/list equivalent of `cat /some/file | sed 's/foo/bar/'` ?

I would like to avoid using a string input with `shell=True` and was wondering if it can be done without creating 2 subprocesses.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe syntax is a shell construct, so you can use the shell to execute it:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen("cat /some/file | sed 's/foo/bar/'", shell=True)
```

But pipes themselves are *not* limited to the shell, so you can establish the pipe in Python:

```
sp1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '/some/file'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sp2 = subprocess.Popen(['sed', 's/foo/bar'], stdin=sp1.stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about the string input with shell=True but I didn't want to use that. I thought about 2 sub processes but I wanted to check if it can be done in just one.

Comment: You cannot. You need two separate processes; the only question is whether Python creates them, or if Python starts a shell to create them.